# Using Eclipse/Subclipse to manage SVN rather than TortoiseSVN

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, tortoisesvn, subclipse

To date I have done all my management of SVN via TortoiseSVN.  I would like to learn a bit more about how to use Eclipse/Subclipse.  The main thing I am trying to figure out is the update.  The issue is this that I need to update more then what is in the Eclipse project.  Here is what things look like in Subversion:

```
trunk
    Clients
    EclipseProjects
        Project1
        Project2
        Project3
        Project4
        Project5
        Project6
        Project7
    JDK
    SQLScripts
```

The issue is that while the Eclipse workspace only contains a few of the Projects# directories, to run the application one must drop to the command line and run it and the application uses ALL the projects.  I also want to be updated the other folders that are at the same level as EclipseProject: Clients, JDK, SQLScripts.

Currently with TortoiseSVN, I simply go to the trunk and do an update.  How can I do that within Eclipse when the trunk is not part of the workspace?

Comment: While you can really *manage* data in Subversion repository via TortoiseSVN, I don't think that a plug-in to Eclipse IDE provides the same functionality. I'd avoid this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subclipse can only operate on what is loaded into your Eclipse workspace.  You have a few options here, not in particular order:

1. Checkout each project separately using Subclipse.  Each project will be its own SVN working copy.
2. Checkout "trunk" using Subclipse.  Just create an Eclipse "simple project" for this checkout.  The individual Eclipse projects can then be Imported into your workspace. So projects will show up twice.  Once as themselves, and once as a folder beneath the trunk project.  If you want to update them all at once, you can take the Update on the trunk project.  But you can still take actions on individual projects too.
3. Same as #2, but do the checkout of trunk using TortoiseSVN.  And use TortoiseSVN when you update everything.  You will need to do Team > Refresh to let Subclipse know you did something in TortoiseSVN.  I would still use Subclipse and import those projects into SVN.  Even if you do all your commit and update actions using TortoiseSVN, there are advantage inside Eclipse to having Subclipse installed and TortoiseSVN and Subclipse can both use the same working copy fine as long as they share the same SVN version.

I use all 3 of these approaches in different scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually quite simple. All you'll have to do is check out the repository using Eclipse check out tool. 
In Eclipse, open **Window > Show View > Other...**, select **SVN Repositories**. Click **New Repository Location**, enter your SVN url, username and password. Once the repository added, do Checkout and voilà.

A little advice based on my experience : do not check out the whole trunk! Because then you will have one big folder trunk in the Project Explorer and it's frustrating open three folders trunk > EclipseProjects > ProjectXYZ everytime to actually get to your project. It's also not very visually pleasant and ordered. What I recommend is checkout the **ProjectX** folders, **Clients**, **JDK** and **SQL Scripts** folders separately. You'll have a nice flat hierarchy like this :

```
 Clients
 Project1
 Project2
 Project3
 Project4
 Project5
 Project6
 Project7
 JDK
 SQLScripts
```

Remember that using this technique, anything outside the scope of these folders (e.g. trunk/EclipseProjects/log.txt) won't be taken into account. If you have anything like that, you can always put it in the separate subfolder of trunk and treat it the same way as others.